# Averaging real time data in Loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyserial

I am currently working with a proximity sensor through a serial port in python.

The data that I am getting corresponds to a distance. My goal is to take every 4 pieces of data and compute the average. I am having trouble coming up with an algorithm for this. I am using the following code:

```
ser = serial.Serial(port = "COM5", baudrate = 230400,  bytesize = 
serial.EIGHTBITS, parity= serial.PARITY_NONE, timeout = 1)
try:
    ser.isOpen()
    print("serial Port is open")
except:
    print("error")
    exit()
if (ser.isOpen()):
    try:

    while True:
        line = ser.readline()

        for position, data in enumerate(line):

            if position == 4:
                print (data)

                    #while position == 4:

                    #seq.append(data)
                    #if len(seq) != 4:
                        #seq.append(data)
                        #print (seq)
                        #while len(seq) == 4:
                        #    print(seq)
                       # break
                   ### 
                    #if len(seq) != 4:
                     #   seq.append(data)
                      #  print(seq)
                       # while len(seq) == 4:
                        #   print(seq)
except Exception:
            print( "Keyboard Interrupt")
else:
        print("cannnot open port")
```

The actual output is shown on the picture:

[image]

To provide a concrete example, from this output:

```
23

27

23

45
```

I would like to format it to just:

```
29.5
```

Comment: `(A + B + C + D) / 4`

Comment: yes I know how to take the average of a data set... I was trying to figure out how to put each output into a list of 4

Comment: You may want to update your question with a more specific version of what you want. `My goal is to take every 4 pieces of data and compute the average. I am having trouble coming up with an algorithm for this. ` I gave you the mean. You say you know this already. What do you actually want then?

Comment: I am streaming real time data so it is constantly changing. I would like the program to be able to automatically take in 4 pieces of the output at one time and the average it out and display the new data. the part I am having trouble with is finding an algorithm to extract 4 pieces at one time. I was hoping to somehow sort the 4 bits into a list and then  producing an average from there

Answer (score 0):

```
# ...
# init your List 
seq = []
# ...
while True:
    # append to your List
    seq.append(line[4]) # short for  for ... enumerate(line) + if position==4 ... data
    # check length of your List
    while len(seq)>4:
       # reduce length of your List
       del seq[0]
    # (A + B + C + D) / 4
    data = sum(seq) / len(seq)
    print(data) # print your fluent mean average
    # ...
```